# Created apache alias directory, but not working

Tags: php, apache, directory, wamp

I have created an apache alias directory so that I can access the directory from outside the root folder with the same url...

The problem is that it refuse to work without a trailing slash.  As an example if the site name is

- www.example.com/aa

error **Cannot find server** appears.

However if I enter

- www.example.com/aa/

it works.

Any Idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why Wamp Server doesn’t do this automatically, I’m not sure, but at least there’s a simple fix.

Click on the Wamp Server icon again and select Apache -> Alias directories -> [alias url] -> Edit alias. This will open the alias file in Notepad. Remove the trailing slash from the relative URL.

For Example

```
Alias /example/ "c:/path/to/example/"
```

Would become

```
Alias /example "c:/path/to/example/"
```

Save the file and close Notepad.

Wamp Server should restart automatically (if not, do it manually). Once it has restarted, you’re alias should now work with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: Oh god I can't believe that. I wasted 3 hours for nothing. Thanks mate.

Comment: For some reason, this did not work for me :-( Calling http://localhost/example showed the directory listing, but if I click on a link, I will be redirected to http://localhost/link instead of http://localhost/example/link . Actually there should be a 301 redirect from /example to /example/

Answer (score 3):

Add a [mod rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /aa /aa/
```

Answer (score 0):

`www.example.com/aa` will make apache first look for a file called `aa`. As it doesn't exists,  you should get a 404 error.

Whereas `www.example.com/aa/` will match your alias directive which works on directories (not files AFAIK). At least I've experienced this on windows.

You might want to use the [`AliasMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) directive instead:

```
AliasMatch ^/icons(.*) /usr/local/apache/icons$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, by the way I implemented the answer given by @Rajat Singhal..and it worked...:)

Comment: Okay, cool, good to know. Might need to check my htconf now ;)